# Java implementation of BST delete node

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to make a method to delete a node in a BST and its not working..I'm using a Node class I made myself.. tried debugging but didnt get much help on addressing the error in the code.

Appreciate any help on how to make it work.

```
public boolean delete(Node z)
{
    if (z == null)
        return false;

    Node x,y;
    if( z.getLeft() == null || z.getRight()== null)
        y = z;
    else { 
        y = (Node) successor(z);
    }
    if (y.getLeft() != null)
        x = y.getLeft();
    else x = y.getRight();
    if(x != null)
        x.setParent(y.getParent());
    if(y.getParent() == null) {
        this.node=x;
    }
    else if (y == y.getParent().getLeft())
    {
            y.getParent().setLeft(x);
    }
        else y.getParent().setRight(x);

    if(y==z)
        z.setKey(y.getKey());
    return true;    
}


public Node treeMinimum(Node x) {
    while (x.getLeft() != null)
        x = x.getLeft();

    return x;
}

public Node successor(Node node) {
    Node x = node;

    if (x.getRight() != null)
        return treeMinimum(x.getRight());

    Node y = x.getParent();
    while (y != null && x == y.getRight()) {
        x = y;
        y = y.getParent();
    }

    return y;
}
```

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting an error (if so, what error?) or is the output not what you expect (if so, what does it look like and what should it look like?)?

Comment: For one thing - I'm willing to bet `if(y==z) z.setKey(y.getKey());` doesn't do anything. You assign the key of the one to the key of the other if they're equal, thus they're **the exact same object** already.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Here is the complete solution
public void delete(final Integer data) {
    root = delete(root, data);
}

public Node<OInfo> delete(Node<OInfo> node, final Integer data) {
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int cmp = data.compareTo(new Integer(node.getData().data));
    if (cmp < 0) {
        node.setLeft(delete(node.getLeft(), data));
    } else if (cmp > 0) {
        node.setRight(delete(node.getRight(), data));
    } else {
        boolean isRoot = false;
        if (root == node) {
            isRoot = true;
        }
        if (node.getLeft() == null) {
            return node.getRight();
        }
        if (node.getRight() == null) {
            return node.getLeft();
        }
        Node<OInfo> t = node;
        node = findMinimum(t.getRight());
        node.setRight(deleteMin(t.getRight()));
        node.setLeft(t.getLeft());
        if (isRoot) {
            root = node;
        }
    }

    return node;
}

private Node<OInfo> deleteMin(Node<OInfo> node) {
if (node.getLeft() == null) {
    return node.getRight();
    }
node.setLeft(deleteMin(node.getLeft()));
return node;
}

private Node<OInfo> findMinimum(Node<OInfo> node) {
if (node == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null value of node provided.");
}

if (node.getLeft() == null) {
    return node;
} else {
    return findMinimum(node.getLeft());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
/**
 * Internal method to remove from a subtree.
 *
 * @param x the item to remove.
 * @param t the node that roots the tree.
 * @return the new root.
 * @throws ItemNotFoundException if x is not found.
 */
protected BinaryNode remove(Comparable x, BinaryNode t) {
    if (t == null) {
        throw new ItemNotFoundException(x.toString());
    }
    if (x.compareTo(t.element) < 0) {
        t.left = remove(x, t.left);
    } else if (x.compareTo(t.element) > 0) {
        t.right = remove(x, t.right);
    } else if (t.left != null && t.right != null) { // Two children
        t.element = findMin(t.right).element;
        t.right = removeMin(t.right);
    } else {
        t = (t.left != null) ? t.left : t.right;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: OP has `parent` reference as well